# Android: how to get a MediaPlayer object from the MainActivity in a Fragment?

Tags: java, android, audio, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I'm developing an android app and i'm using `NavigationDrawer`, there is only one activity (`MainActivity`) and Fragments.
I have a radio live stream button on the `ActionBar` so i made an object of `MediaPlayer` in the `MainActivity` for the live stream button and it's working fine, now i have some sound files in one of the fragments, i want to get the `mediaPlayer` object that i made in the MainActivity in order to use it. Note that the live stream button is always visible at the top of the application so if i'm in a fragment that has a sound file i want to be able to listen to the sound file and if i clicked on the live stream button the sound file will be paused and live stream will be on.

Here's my code:
This is MainActivity (only the relative part):

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

   private static final String RADIO_STREAM_URL= "http://198.178.123.23:8662/stream/1/;listen.mp3";
   MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
       mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
       mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
       try {
           mediaPlayer.setDataSource(RADIO_STREAM_URL);
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

       return true;
   }
   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (item != null )
    {
        if(item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home){
            if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.END)){
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.END);
            } else {
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.END);
            }
        }else if(item.getItemId() == R.id.action_settings){
            try {
                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                        mediaPlayer.stop();
                        Log.e("ANA Radio","was playing");
                    }else{
                        Log.e("ANA Radio","was not playing");

                        mediaPlayer.start();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    }
    return false;
}
```

Now how to get the `mediaPlayer` object in a Fragment ?

Comment: If the `Activity` 'owns' the `MediaPlayer` then it should be solely responsible for the playing of the radio stream and the sound files. Define a callback `interface` in the `Fragment` and implement its method(s) in your `Activity`. Then you can simply pass the path / uri from the `Fragment` to the `Activity` and it will then handle control of playback.

Comment: Can you show me that in coding please ?

Comment: Just look at the Android dev site. This link explains callbacks. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here try this:
In your fragment you can write the code below to get the MediaPlayer object:

```
((MainActivity)getActivity()).mediaPlayer
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is that, you make your mediaPlayer a member of a class. To do that go like this:

```
public static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
```